# Stuck in a Method of Integration (Reduction Formulae)

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

So, I believe there are many ways to solve this and I have solved this too. But I want help in my particular Method that is :

**Method 1**

I started with

$$I_{n+2}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n+2} \theta d\theta$$

Then I followed:

$$I_{n+2}= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n} \theta (1-\cos^2 \theta)d\theta$$

$$I_{n+2}= I_n - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n} \theta \cos^2 \theta d\theta$$

> And **Bang!** I can't continue from here, I'm stuck

---

Determined to solve this by myself, I tried a trick and I got it right, here it is :

$$I_{n+2}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n+2} \theta d\theta$$

> Let $m= n+2$

$$I_{m}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{m} \theta d\theta$$

$$I_{m}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{m-1} \theta \sin \theta d\theta$$

$$I_{m}=[\sin^{m-1}\theta (-\cos \theta)]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} cos \theta ((m-1) \sin^{m-2} \theta \cos \theta)d\theta$$

Simplifying Further I finally get :

$$I_m= \frac {m-1}{m} I_{m-2}$$

Replacing $m=n+2$

And Tarda, I get the result:

$$I_{n+2}=\frac{n+1}{n+2} I_n$$

---

Having solved it successfully, I now want to go back to my first method, And I wonder how would one **continue** from the last step in my method 1 and get it solved.

> I know that there are many other ways to solve this, (ie. Reversal of Differentiation a Product). But I am interested in understanding the technique of the method I can't do, so how can one continue and solve from my method 1.

Comment: You can write 
$$(\sin(\theta)^{n}(\cos(\theta)^2=(\frac{(\sin(\theta))^{n+1}}{n+1})^{\prime} \cos(\theta)$$ and integrate by parts.

Comment: @Kelenner , Woooah Great :) Thanks, Could you add this as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write 
$$\sin^{n}\theta\cos^2\theta=\left(\frac{\sin^{n+1}\theta}{n+1}\right)^{\prime}\cos \theta$$ and then integrate by parts.

Comment: (Upvoted!) Thank You, I just finished testing it, got the result ;)

Comment: Your latex powers has some issues, could you fix it ? :) It would be helpful for future users.

Comment: I edited it :))